# Got error: `RangeError: invalid time value` while set XAxis date value use date-fns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I am using recharts to present a data array as an area chart.
My code fetches `mydata` array from a remote API with the lines below:

```js
const [myData, setMyData] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
const getData = async () => {
      const resp =  await fetch('https://api.contoso.xyz/api');
      const jsonResp = await resp.json();
      setMyData(jsonResp);
    };

    getData();
    }, []);
```

the data JSON array looks like this:

```
[
{"date": "2022-03-01",
"value": 123456,
},
{"date": "2022-03-02",
"value": 100000,
}
]
```

The React chart component looks like this:

```
...
import { format, parseISO } from date-fns
...
<ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height={400}>
  <AreaChart data={mydata} >
      <Area type="monotone" dataKey="value" stroke="#82CA9D" fill="#82CA9D" />
      <XAxis dataKey="date" tickFormatter={(str) => {
              const dateObj = parseISO(str);
              return format(dateObj, "MMM d");
            }}/>
     <YAxis />
     <Tooltip />
     <CartesianGrid opacity={0.5}/>
  </AreaChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

When run the react site, I am getting the errors below

```
RangeError: Invalid time value
    at Em (main.5e916930.js:2:575929)
    at tickFormatter (main.5e916930.js:2:577712)
    at Function.value (main.5e916930.js:2:406091)
    at Function.value (main.5e916930.js:2:404369)
    at a.value (main.5e916930.js:2:402724)
    at a.value (main.5e916930.js:2:403854)
    at Eu (main.5e916930.js:2:143688)
    at Su (main.5e916930.js:2:143484)
    at pl (main.5e916930.js:2:178073)
    at lc (main.5e916930.js:2:163912)
```

The weird thing is if I change the `XAxis` section to something below, the local run will actually show the chart successfully.

```js
<XAxis dataKey="date" tickFormatter={(str) => {
              const dateObj = parseISO(str);
              return format(dateObj, "MMM d");
              return str;
            }}/>
```

Now if I remove `return str;` from the above section of code, the chart will still work locally.
When the chart didn't work, if I add `console.log(str)` in front of `const dateObj = parseISO(str);`, the output I get in console is showing `auto` instead of the actual date string.

Not sure what caused this kind behavior. Anyone know what is going on with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what the problem is. The `myData` array is not yet populated when the page initially loaded (Because fetch is async?). That caused the `str` value to be `auto` or `0` (Don't know exactly why). This happens every time I re-started the test site locally. If I change the code while the local test site is already up, the chart loads successfully without issue as the array has already been populated.

To get rid of this issue, I added a check condition before reformat the date string.

```js
if ( str === 'auto' || str === 0){
      return str;
}else{
      console.log(str
      const dateObj = parseISO(str);
      return format(dateObj, "MMM d");
  }
```

Not sure if this is the best way to solve this kind problem. Any better suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing missing you might have missed parsing your `string` date to `Date` type. `format` from `date-fns` throws `RangeError: Invalid time value` when you pass a string as input.

Below is the sandbox with your code it's working perfectly.

[image: Edit pedantic-tereshkova-fyolu1]